# jvm.dll missing error when launching application

Tags: windows, dll, path, java

I was trying to run CapeClear SOA Editor application on Windows 7 64bit but it would not start and produced an error saying that it couldn't load jvm.dll.  I have 64 bit JDK version 7u13 installed.

**The only thing that worked** was to install the 32 bit version of the JDK and then set JAVA_HOME variable to point to the 32 bit version `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_13`

Why is this happening?  What can I do to resolve the issue so that my JAVA_HOME is pointing to the 64 bit JDK and SOA Editor application launches without errors?

P.S.
I tried copying jvm.dll from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\jre\bin\server` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\jre\bin\client` into the same directly as SOAEditor.exe but that didn't help.

Update1:
Using listdll.exe I verified that SOA Editor loaded `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll`

Update2:
Adding `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\jre\bin\client\` to the path variable didn't help either

Comment: You said copying the dll didn't help does it mean that it still can not find the dll or it actually find the dll but the program fail?

Comment: Couldn't find the dll.  Same error message.

Answer (score 0):

In a command prompt you might want to try to register the file with:

> regsvr32 jvm.dll

Also, it should be noted that mixing 32bit and 64bit installs and DLLs is a very bad idea.